# Cart page crashes FirebaseRecyclerAdapter problem

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

This is my cart class. Here every code is working perfectly but only the cart page crashes when the app is run. I am confused about how the error happened. 
The problem is on this block below:

```
if(session.getCartValue()>0) {
              populateRecyclerView();
}
```

When this method is called, it just crashes. When the cart has an empty list, it works well. I am sure that the populateRecyclerView() has the problem. But I couldn't figure out the problem.

Here is my code:

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

    //to get user session data
    private UserSession session;
    private HashMap<String,String> user;
    private String name,email,photo,mobile;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    //Getting reference to Firebase Database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = database.getReference();
    private LottieAnimationView tv_no_item;
    private LinearLayout activitycartlist;
    private LottieAnimationView emptycart;

    private ArrayList<SingleProductModel> cartcollect;
    private float totalcost=0;
    private int totalproducts=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Cart");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        //check Internet Connection
        new CheckInternetConnection(this).checkConnection();

        //retrieve session values and display on listviews
        getValues();

        //SharedPreference for Cart Value
        session = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());

        //validating session
        session.isLoggedIn();

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        tv_no_item = findViewById(R.id.tv_no_cards);
        activitycartlist = findViewById(R.id.activity_cart_list);
        emptycart = findViewById(R.id.empty_cart);
        cartcollect = new ArrayList<>();

        if (mRecyclerView != null) {
            //to enable optimization of recyclerview
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
        //using staggered grid pattern in recyclerview
        mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        if(session.getCartValue()>0) {
              populateRecyclerView();

        }else if(session.getCartValue() == 0)  {
            tv_no_item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            activitycartlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptycart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void populateRecyclerView() {

        //Say Hello to our new FirebaseUI android Element, i.e., FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SingleProductModel,MovieViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SingleProductModel, MovieViewHolder>(
                SingleProductModel.class,
                R.layout.cart_item_layout,
                MovieViewHolder.class,
                //referencing the node where we want the database to store the data from our Object
                mDatabaseReference.child("cart").child(mobile).getRef()

        ) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final MovieViewHolder viewHolder, final SingleProductModel model, final int position) {
                if(tv_no_item.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
                    tv_no_item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                viewHolder.cardname.setText(model.getPrname());
                viewHolder.cardprice.setText("NRs."+model.getPrprice());
                viewHolder.cardcount.setText("Quantity : "+model.getNo_of_items());
                Picasso.with(Cart.this).load(model.getPrimage()).into(viewHolder.cardimage);

                totalcost += model.getNo_of_items()*Float.parseFloat(model.getPrprice());
                totalproducts += model.getNo_of_items();
                cartcollect.add(model);


                viewHolder.carddelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(Cart.this,getItem(position).getPrname(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        getRef(position).removeValue();
                        session.decreaseCartValue();
                        startActivity(new Intent(Cart.this,Cart.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void checkout(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Cart.this,OrderDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("totalprice",Float.toString(totalcost));
        intent.putExtra("totalproducts",Integer.toString(totalproducts));
        intent.putExtra("cartproducts",cartcollect);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    //viewHolder for our Firebase UI
    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView cardname;
        ImageView cardimage;
        TextView cardprice;
        TextView cardcount;
        ImageView carddelete;

        View mView;
        public MovieViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mView = v;
            cardname = v.findViewById(R.id.cart_prtitle);
            cardimage = v.findViewById(R.id.image_cartlist);
            cardprice = v.findViewById(R.id.cart_prprice);
            cardcount = v.findViewById(R.id.cart_prcount);
            carddelete = v.findViewById(R.id.deletecard);
        }
    }


    private void getValues() {

        //create new session object by passing application context
        session = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());

        //validating session
        session.isLoggedIn();

        //get User details if logged in
        user = session.getUserDetails();

        name = user.get(UserSession.KEY_NAME);
        email = user.get(UserSession.KEY_EMAIL);
        mobile = user.get(UserSession.KEY_MOBiLE);
        photo = user.get(UserSession.KEY_PHOTO);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    public void viewProfile(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Cart.this,Profile.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //check Internet Connection
        new CheckInternetConnection(this).checkConnection();

    }

    public void Notifications(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(Cart.this,NotificationActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

My logcat displays this:

```
E/OneSignal: Error updating the user record because of th enull user id

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.beingdev.magicprint, PID: 10699
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
        at com.firebase.ui.a.b.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source:45)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.createViewHolder(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source:435)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source:5)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.c(Unknown Source:1)
        at android.support.v7.widget.as.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source:86)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source:357)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source:1)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.N(Unknown Source:42)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.q(Unknown Source:48)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.d(Unknown Source:109)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(Unknown Source:41)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
        at com.firebase.ui.a.b.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source:25)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.createViewHolder(Unknown Source:6) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source:435) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source:5) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.c(Unknown Source:1) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.as.a(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source:86) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source:357) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source:1) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.N(Unknown Source:42) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.q(Unknown Source:48) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.d(Unknown Source:109) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(Unknown Source:41) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
        at com.firebase.ui.a.b.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source:45)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.createViewHolder(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source:435)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source:5)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.c(Unknown Source:1)
        at android.support.v7.widget.as.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source:86)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source:357)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source:1)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.N(Unknown Source:42)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.q(Unknown Source:48)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.d(Unknown Source:109)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(Unknown Source:41)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
        at com.firebase.ui.a.b.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source:25)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.createViewHolder(Unknown Source:6) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source:435) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source:5) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.c(Unknown Source:1) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.as.a(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source:86) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source:357) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source:1) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.N(Unknown Source:42) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.q(Unknown Source:48) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.d(Unknown Source:109) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(Unknown Source:41) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Cart, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-7755245950036280198, timestamp=1589356676240, fatal=1}]
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 532
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=532, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Cart, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-7755245950036280198}]
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10699 SIG: 9
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding details to Proguard rules. 
We need to keep the packages inside proguardrules.pro file so that proguard won't stop it from running.